# How can I block direct access to my JavaScript files?

Tags: php, javascript, minify

I use Minify to minify and cache all my script requests. **I only want my users to be able to access the minified versions of the JavaScript files.**

Minify lies at `www.example.com/min` and my scripts are at `www.example.com/scripts`. How can I block direct access to `doc_root/scripts` which is where my unminified JavaScript files lie. I'd rather not put them out of the document root but it's an option.

Please note that I'm using Zend Framework, so the actual root of my application is shifted to `www.example.com/public`. An htaccess file handles the rewrite.

Comment: What problem is preventing direct access supposed to solve?

Comment: I include comments in my unminfied JavaScript code (as does mostly everyone else). It's a pain to manually minify my code come deployment and be sure I upload the right version. I use Minify to do this automatically, but the unminified versions are still out in the open.

Comment: The real solution is to make CSS and JS files just as secret as PHP files are. This either means executing them somehow on the server, which doesn't seem useful or possible, or hiding them using a truly secure browser access tunnel, which might not be possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can't you just use an .htaccess file inside `doc_root/scripts` to prevent all access over the web to `.js` files over HTTP?

It won't stop minify, since that provides *indirect* access.

So in `doc_root/scripts/.htaccess`, something along the lines of

```
<Files ~ "\.js$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Note that the location of the `.htaccess` file matters in this case.

Comment: Thank you, the rewrite rule worked. I'll accept this once SO lets me.

Answer (score 5):

You effectively can't block end-user facing code. Even if you served it with PHP or another server-side language and blocked direct requests, it's of course still possible to read it directly with a number of tools.

You should code with this in mind and be mindful with javascript comments, business knowledge, etc.

UPDATE:

However, if you're talking about code that doesn't ever need to be accessed by an end-user, you could as you mentioned move it out of the server root, or you can block the files in your directory (or an entire directory). It's easy with Apache's .htaccess.

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

You could also redirect the source files to the minified versions with mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /scripts/(.*)$ /min/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I could care less about them getting their hands on the minified versions. I know that anyone determined enough can make sense of them. I'd just rather them not see the comments in my unminified code.

Comment: Oh, I misread. You just want to block the source files, not the minified ones. I'll update my answer.

Comment: then don't save the original un-minned version in a publiclly accessible area. Move them outside the document root, and if you can't do that, put them into an "unguessable" subdirectory and don't refer to it in any public-face pages.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server you're using. Assuming it's Apache, you can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<Directory ~ "\scripts">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Or something to that effect..

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to check referers, and not everyone sends them, or sends a real one. In other words, you can't block direct access to anyone who really wants something. It's impossible to determine with 100% accuracy if a request is a direct one or is being done via a `<script src=....>` type request.

Answer (score 0):

For your Javascript to actually run the user's browser must be able to read it ultimately.
As such there's no real way to "block" access to your scripts folder (well to be precise you can but that would break your website since the browser would not see the files in order to run them.)

One solution could be obfuscation, which makes the javascript code harder to read / understand but ultimately the user will see the code, and with a bit of persevering reverse engineering it can be de-obfuscated.

Another thing i've seen someone do is creating an "empty" js.html page, and insert all their javascript into script tags in the page (embedded, not external), and from his main page make ann ajax request to js.html and embed it at the bottom of the page. kind of a round about way but the user will not see the js when viewing the source unless using developper tools such as firebug.

Note that the last option also might cause some delay depending on the abount of code you are loading. but here the key is not blocking access to your scripts, but just making them harder to obtain / read / copy.

Edit: oops, misread as well. I think the best solution in this case would be to go with an htaccess file in your scripts folder denying all access

Answer (score 0):

This answer is little bit newer, than question (only several years, that’s nothing)

You cannot deny access to JavaScript file, because they wont’t be accessible from `<script>` tag.

But I found a workaround:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.js$ /invalid.html [R=301,L]
```

Place it in your .htaccess file in your home folder of web. (under htdocs or public_html).
This will automatically redirect everyone from it. So they don’t see it.

Comment: This will create the same problem though. The script tag will just load `invalid.html` and the JS code will never get executed.

Comment: Really? So if you include the script with a `<script>` tag it gets executed and if you access the `.js` file directly from the browser it gets redirected?