# How to prevent direct access to CSS and JS files

Tags: php, html, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I block direct access to my JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335644/how-can-i-block-direct-access-to-my-javascript-files)

I have a folder and inside it there are around five more which looks like following:

```
 1.asset(folder)
       1.1 css (subfolder)
              1.1.1 style.css (file)
       1.2 javascript (subfolder)
                     1.2.1 validation.js (file)
 // goes on like this
```

Now my question is how to prevent my css to appear when any user hits - my_base_url/asset/css/style.css on the browse?

I tried blank index.html but it doesn't work. I also tried using "deny from all" .htaccess file but in this case when I load my website it doesn't find the CSS..

Comment: This is not possible, reliably.

Comment: It's useless to try. If the user's browser downloads the file, how can you stop the user from getting it?

Comment: "Are you a browser? Then read my file and store it in your cache, but don't ever, ever let the user see it. Deal?"

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  CSS and JS files have no meaning outside of the browser so why try to prevent the browser from getting them?  If you're trying to stop people reading your JS files, then trust me, there's nothing in there that's so important or amazing that it needs to be protected from prying eyes

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking for is, technically, impossible.

In order for the browser to be able to use the CSS, it must have access to it. Ditto Javascript.

The best you can do is *obfuscate* the sources. You could do this by using a processed language - such as Stylus or LessCSS for CSS, and Coffeescript for JS - or by making the delivery more complicated. You could minify the script files, or even have them dynamically generated and fetched (in small pieces) by another JS file.

However, anything you do can be reverse-engineered, because the users **must be able to access the rules in order for the browser to use them**.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you don't want to show the directory listing for your css and js directories, add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

from: http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml

Answer (score 0):

First of all, preventing direct link to the css file doesn't mean that other people can't see the content. Most browsers have features to inspect the files loaded, which includes your css.

One thing you could do is put everything under WEB-INF folder and have controllers to load all your static resources. I can't think of a reason why you want to do this though.