# Block direct access to js, css file but allow access from index.html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

This is my directory look like:

- index.html
- data.js
- .htaccess

Content in index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="data.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is:

- I don't want user to see my `data.js` by direct link like `www.sample.com/data.js`
- But `data.js` still allow access from `index.html`

I tried in .htaccess like:

```
deny from all
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|css|js|png)$ - [F]
```

But it alway block access from index.html too.

Thanks.

Comment: Impossible. That isn't how the Internet works. Whatever solutions you invent will be trivially easy to bypass.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335644/how-can-i-block-direct-access-to-my-javascript-files) it's a little different, he don't want any access to that file, and i want my index.html still can access.

Comment: I'm telling you, that's impossible. There is no difference between the user "directly" accessing the file, and indirectly accessing it through your index.html. You cannot prevent one and allow the other.

Comment: Are there some way to do this by go thought php or something, because i really need it.

Comment: **No**. What part of **Impossible** aren't you getting? At best, you can obfuscate your code to make it less readable to humans, but you cannot *prevent* people from seeing it. No site anywhere on the Internet does this. Somehow, the Internet continues to function in spite of this "limitation". If a JavaScript file can be accessed by a browser, it can be read by humans. End of story.

Comment: its possible but not the way u thinking.
even its possible without `htaccess` `deny` keyword.
`1st` u can not use or send `.js/.css` file to client, so use jscript.php
`2st` u need a `MVC` framework.
`3rd` at top of the file `header type js/css`.
`4th` if `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` have index.php and no direct access. if not then `die()`.
`5th` write your js/css code.
** This method will not allow Search Engine. if u want to allow then filter in `4th step`.

Comment: If your goal is to use JS or CSS on your site and prevent it to be visible in the browser via Developer tools etc. or via direct file access, then it is very much possible to do so using a relatively simple method. (PHP example on how to include "invisible" js)
Create a PHP script file, eg. jsscript.php that echoes all your JS data.
Then in index.php you include the JS using jQuery.getScript.
In jsscript.php you can then make an if statement and only echo the JS  if referer equals e.g. http://xxxxxx.xxx/index.php
If you try to access jsscript.php directly in browser the output is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My tips are easily bypassed**, but without be careful, we can be trapped.

## Only live view of the page

You can replace or remove *script tag* with javascript for hide this in live view of the page. But if you watch directly the network, you can see easily the javascript file/code.

```
<div id="RemoveMe0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //This code it is hidden to live view.
        var my_var = 5 + 5;

        $('#RemoveMe0').remove();
        //or document.getElementById("RemoveMe0").innerHTML = "";
    </script>
</div>
```

For include javascript :

```
<div id="RemoveMe1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/MyJS.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Your include it is hidden to live view.
        $('#RemoveMe1').remove();
    </script>
</div>
```

---

## Only direct view

Put your files in an HTML file (myfile.js to myfile.html), like this on a direct view you can execute a javascript function.

```
function Hello() {
    alert("Hello");
}
Hello();
//<script>document.body.innerHTML = "";</script>
```

Or if you don't want to rename your file, you can to use .htaccess file to modify file header.

```
AddType text/html .js
```

---

## Or minize/parse your JS

You can use tool like this :

- [minize your js](http://p2p.wrox.com/145194-post2.html) : This tool use eval function, and try to complicate your script.
- [Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx) : Complicates the code for beginners, it's easy to by-pass.
- [Google Closure JS Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) : Optimize, compress, and minify your code. **It is a natural tool for the production environment**.
- [Javascript to Asm.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/asmjs-javascript-compile-target/)

Comment: Or you could just use `document.currentScript`

Answer (score 5):

> I don't want user to see or download my data.js by direct link like
>   www.sample.com/data.js

### Not possible.

The JS is going to be rendered on the client-side i.e. It will be downloaded to cache, no matter what you do to protect it.

Comment: Thanks, i just want user can not view it by direct access, that's enough with me.

Comment: @user972611 That's impossible, no matter how much you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a search before asking questions .There are lot of search results available for such topic.

Some of the links:

**1.** [How to prevent direct access to CSS and JS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951052/how-to-prevent-direct-access-to-css-and-js-files)

**2..** http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/287331/Prevent-user-from-viewing-CSS-or-Javascript-of-any

.
.
.
 *and more ...*

---

All have a common answer which is : ***You cannot hide/block CSS or JS files from access by visitors.In other words "IMPOSSIBLE"***

Comment: It is possible using .htaccess please research before answering questions.

Comment: @Dre_Dre its good if its possible .Why don't you add an answer to this post .I have no problems if that proves my answer is wrong .I will be happy to learn something new