# Deny access to js assets. Recommendable? How to do it?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I need to deny public users to see the js frameworks we use in our website.
 I have Apache 2.x version with php and js. 
First my question is, is it recommendable? I mean, wouldn't denying access to the directory will also block Apache to parse the framework and use it?
Second, how can I achieve it? I have tried with
 
`RedirectMatch 404 /var/www/html/js/.* example.com` following this guide: https://alvinalexander.com/web/apache-redirectmatch-examples-wildcard-301
Also I have tried with a .htaccess file in /js directory with just `deny from all` on it and even a `<Directory "/var/www/html/js"> </Directory>` with `Options -Indexes` and `deny from all` but got no luck.
What is the correct way of doing this?

### EDIT

This is part of a pentest result that has been done to my server and the auditors are saying the public access to /js directory and frameworks within it is a security problem so, I'm trying to look for a way to deny access or well, find a way to justify the access to this directory

Comment: If you deny access to the code the site needs to run, why would it work?

Comment: That's why I need to find a way to stop public users to see it whilst keeping the site working

Comment: I have a feeling you're trying to solve a problem you don't have. Also, that's impossible, since the user's browser needs the code to run it.

Comment: Yeah, i feel the same. Let me edit the question to understand better the background

Comment: Who are those `auditors` anyway...what you can do is to store your javascript files in a cdn or something similar...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block direct access to js, css file but allow access from index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931658/block-direct-access-to-js-css-file-but-allow-access-from-index-html)

Comment: Your security people seem to have strange notions about how the web works.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the same. Checking the other post.

Comment: The answer is quite simple tough.  And it is...you cannot, right? Because js is client-side so the idea is for the public to download and parse the js directory and if that cannot be done, the site would'nt work well...
The problem here is explaining, gotta do some long blah blah document

Answer (score 0):

The answer is...it cannot be done, as it is a part of how javascript works and it has to be visible in order for the website to work