# Redirect all file in folder to another page, but still allow html file access

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

I have directory like

- index.html
- datafolder (all my js and css file in here)

I want every direct access to file in `datafolder` like: `www.sample.com/data/main.js`  will redirect to some error page (404,403, anything) or redirect to `www.sample.com`

### But index.html still can access these files.

(please answer if you have any solution)

Thank you so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I block direct access to my JavaScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335644/how-can-i-block-direct-access-to-my-javascript-files)

Comment: I believe its not duplicate since OP wants `index.html` to be able to access those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
# change this to your actual domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^datafolder(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks but i still can access to files in folder by direct link, this is what i wrote, content-data is my folder [image](http://s1290.photobucket.com/user/user972611/media/Capture_zpscbdab1d6.png.html?filters[user]=138823174&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0)

Comment: Did you replace `domain.com` with your actual domain name? Where did you place above .htaccess fil? Are mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled &working?

Comment: Question1: Yes.  Question2: I put in my document root (public_html) like you said. Question3: I don't know, how can i know if it enabled and working?