# Include script files on codeigniter view file

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am including a script file using the following line:

```
<script src="<?php echo FCPATH;?>includes/js/script_admin_index.js"></script>
```

But the error I am getting is:

```
GET http://localhost/var/www/treed/treed_admin/includes/js/script_admin_index.js (404 NOT FOUND)
```

instead of including the files.

I dont want to use base_url as user will be able to navigate and see the file through the browser as well.

Comment: change FCPATH to base_url();

Comment: I dont want to use base_url as user will be able to navigate and see the file through the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you just said makes sense. `base_url` is the correct way to go.

Comment: @Karthiprime As the script is client side code, you can't hide it from the user. You could obfuscate it though.

Comment: why not try this..instead using fcpath..manually type the url
here localhost/folder/etc.. 

the guy above doesn't understand your problem well..you already said you don't want to use base_url but they insist to force you to use that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `base_url()` to include the javascript file in your VIEW.

For ex.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

For CSS you can use [link_tag](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html).

For ex: `<?php echo link_tag('css/AdminLTE.css'); ?>`

You will need the **URL** helper and **html** helper.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('html');
```

You can block direct all to js and css file.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335644/how-can-i-block-direct-access-to-my-javascript-files)